# return conditional string in java conditional in string

Tags: java, string

Ok so I have a set of strings that I will be returning based on age. I need help with 
 configuring string 4 based on the age of the turtle.

```
private static final String string1 = "food budget-$3.00 per day or $10.00 per week.";
private static final String string2 = "food budget 2 - $2.00 per day or $7.00 per week.";
private static final String string3 = "food budget 3 - $1.00 per day or $5.00 per week.";
private static final String string4 = "food budget 4 - $%4.2f per day or $%5.2f per week.";
```

string4 is a (male turtle, age 66+ and female turtles, age 63+) 
string4 is string1 plus $2.00 for each year over age 65 (male) or 62 (female), per day 
    or
string1 plus $5.00 for each year over age 65 (male) or 62 (female), per week.
here is my method for ages.... so how can make this statement true in my 4th string?

```
private static String calcRateClass(int turtle, String food)
{
  while(gender.equals("m"))
    if(turtle > 32 && turtle < 64)
        return string1;
   if(turtle > 24 && turtle < 31)
     return string3;
   if (turtle > 65)
     return string4; 
  else
  while(gender.equals("f"))
    if(age > 29 && age < 63)
       return string1;
    if(turtle > 24 && turtle < 30)
      return string2;
   if (turtle > 62)
     return string4;
}
```

Can I add the math right into the string4?

Comment: ok I've figured this much out...putting it into my method...    return string.format(RISK_RATE_3, ((age-65)) * 2.0 + 40), ((age-65) * 5.0 + 200));

Comment: I think the statement `while(gender.equals("m"))` is one of the oddest I've ever seen.  I'm trying to imagine an actual scenario in which someone would write that code.

Comment: @jazzbassrob It would make more sense if we were talking about species that exhibited [sequential hermaphroditism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_hermaphroditism).  But I don't think turtles qualify.

Comment: @zer0veritas Before you go any further, you really need to go back and study how control statements work and what they're for (`while`, `if`, etc.), and how to use curly braces (`{`, `}`) to group statements together into a compound statement.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I add the math right into the string4?

No.  Business logic should go in methods.